# Phpseclib does not work from Openshift but works from local machine(Outside Lan)

Tags: ssh, openshift, ssh-keys, openssh, phpseclib

I deployed my code on openshift-online. From there I trying to connect my other server( lets say Machine A on different network) my script. Machine-A is running openssh server on port 4444 (Ubuntu 14.04):

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1)

include("../vendor/autoload.php");
include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');
define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_SIMPLE);
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('mywebsite.redirectme.net', 4444);
$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('id_rsa'));
if (!$ssh->login('myusername', $key)) {
    echo $ssh->getLog();
    exit('Login Failed');

}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('whoami');
echo $ssh->getLog();
?>
```

But it always returns `Permission denied`:

```
/var/lib/openshift/849bc49*************/app-root/runtime/repo/ssh/test.php on line 5 Notice: Cannot connect to myusername.redirectme.net:4444. Error 13. Permission denied in /var/lib/openshift/849bc49*************/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php on line 966
```

`ls -l` on that directory on openshift shows:

```
-rw-------. 1 849bc49************* 849bc49*************  887 Dec 28 02:05 id_rsa
-rw-------. 1 849bc49************* 849bc49*************  237 Dec 28 02:05 id_rsa.pub
```

First I copied ssh key-pair on machine-B & manually copied it to `~/.ssh/authorized-keys` on machine-A. Then I push entire folder (with rsa-keys & scripts) to openshift.

I can connect from machine-B(on different netwok...not a localhost) with same code without any problem. So I am guessing its not really the problem with phpseclib or permission with ssh-keys.

Does Openshift (online) itself force some restriction? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/587#issuecomment-68261192 probably provides an answer to your question.

Comment: @neubert Not it doesn't. I posted that question on github thinking it was a phpseclib issue. But apparently its not because it works from heroku as well. The solution provided on that on that question was provided for selinux, but I am running Ubuntu. I am yet to find solution for fsockopen related problem on Ubuntu. May be the problem is with openshift.

Comment: Sounds like this is a question better suited for superuser.com. And rather than use the overhead of phpseclib (since you're problem ultimately not with phpseclib) just try to connect to that IP / port with fsockopen. Don't send anything to that IP / port, however - just try to connect and you should get the same error.

Comment: It's Selinux. That's the problem. Heroku and other (based on Ubuntu) do not have this problem. You simply can not use `fsockopen` on openshift. Very stupid and silly. No wonder nobody uses Openshift these days.